# Uniqueidentifier vs id convencional (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, rendimiento

Buen día, hoy quiero hacer una pregunta sobre rendimiento (tiempo) sobre que es más eficiente, sí tener un id convencional, tipo `INT`, o sí tener una columna tipo `UniqueIdentifier`.

Con respecto a la declaración son prácticamente iguales, la diferencia es que al `UniqueIdentifier` no se le aplica `IDENTITY`, si no un `DEFAULT NEWID()`

```
CREATE TABLE miTablaConvencional
(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    campo VARCHAR(1)
)

CREATE TABLE miTablaUnique
(
    id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NEWID(),
    campo VARCHAR(1)
)
```

Cual de las dos tablas sería más eficiente, sí se tuviera que hacer consultas por medio de comparar sus campos de llave primaria y por qué.

Nota:

[Aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187942.aspx) y [aquí](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms190215(v=sql.105).aspx), dejo información sobre el `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`

Comment: Así como está, SQL Server creará el primary key como un "clustered index" (esto es el comportamiento por defecto). Tener un índice clustered como `NEWID()` es una idea terrible. Al ser un valor casi aleatorio, cada nueva fila que insertes debe "mover" **todos** los datos que ya tiene la tabla, para volver a dejarlos ordenados físicamente en el disco (al ser clustered). Además esto particionará el disco enormemente también

Comment: Me parece raro que sea una mala práctica, siendo esto la forma recomendada por Microsoft de hacer una tabla que tenga un índice de tipo uniqueidentifier, y además esta es la forma en que maneja los índices Azure.

Comment: Puedes mostrar dónde Microsoft recomienda esta forma para un índice de tipo uniqueidentifier?

Comment: Con respecto a los links que agregaste, definitivamente no veo ninguna recomendación de parte de microsoft acerca de esto. Es más, en ese link hay una sección explicando algunas de las desventajas

Comment: [Enlace de Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/uniqueidentifier-and-clustered-indexes/)

Comment: Me estoy perdiendo algo?, el link que acabas de mostrar dice textualmente: `It isn’t a good idea to create a clustered index on a uniqueidentifier column and generate your GUIDs with NEWID().`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo voy a poner de otra forma.

Para hacer comparaciones las dos formas son exactamente iguales.

Sin embargo, como bien especificaste en los links, usar un uniqueId es un problema a la hora de hacer inserts. Tienes que sacarte de encima el clustered index y aplicarlo a otro campo de ser necesario. Ademas se hacen bastante poco legibles los ID.

Azure los usa porque como estas en la nube, y tu base podría estar distribuida, los necesita para poder hacer merge o particionar la tabla. Sin embargo, seria poco recomendable para una base corporativa o casera. El overhead que se le agrega no vale la pena.